# UPnP SSDP over WI-FI direct in Android

Tags: android-wifi, upnp, wifi-direct

this is in reference to the link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=40003

the topic is about UPnP SSDP over WI-FI direct . 
I have a Galaxy note and Galaxy s3 , i have a simple Server/Client application. galaxy s3 is server , which i am trying to connect using Galaxy note (client) over WI_FI direct .

the server will be detected using UPnP SSDP discovery . When i see the pcap logs , there is notify from client to server but there is no M Search happening . I not am sure whether this is  the right behaviour .

Is this a known problem ?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem.  UPnP devices should send periodic multicast advertisements to inform potential clients on the network that they've appeared or are still available.  This will happen regardless of the presence of control points on the network.

Comment: it is due to this error i was facing this situation sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)